# Number of parameters in Keras/Tensorflow Dense layers

Tags: neural-networks, tensorflow, keras

I am a bit confused about how the number of parameters are calculated in Dense model for the Kera/Tensorflow.

For example, in the figure below I thought that both the statements were the same, but I found a different number of parameters for both.  In particular, I am talking about `model.add(Dense(...))` command.

[image: The models in consideration]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [the documentation for `Dense`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Dense) layer:

> **Note:** If the input to the layer has a rank greater than 2, then Dense computes the dot product between the inputs and the kernel along the last axis of the inputs and axis 1 of the kernel (using tf.tensordot). For example, if input has dimensions (batch_size, d0, d1), then we create a kernel with shape (d1, units), and the kernel operates along axis 2 of the input, on every sub-tensor of shape (1, 1, d1) (there are batch_size * d0 such sub-tensors). The output in this case will have shape (batch_size, d0, units).

That is what happening in your first case - for input dimensions `(4,1)` you've got `d0=4` and `d1=1`. So it creates a kernel of shape `(1,32)` that gets applied along the axis of dimension 4. That's why your output shape is `(4,32)` and you've got 32 weights + 32 biases = 64 parameters.

In second case you've got a "standard" 32 * 4 fully-connected weight matrix + 32 biases = 160.